# How to find max value and its associated field values of each type in SQL?

Tags: sql

```
class sid sname mark
 1A   1   Pete  330
 1A   2   Pet   150
 1B   3   Pe    100
 1B   4   Pe    20
 1C   5   Peter 30
```

how to select the student information from each class who has the highest mark?

I can only do this

```
SELECT MAX(mark), class FROM student GROUP BY class
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
inner join
(
  select class, max(mark) as maxmark
  from your_table
  group by class
) t2 on t1.class = t2.class and t1.mark = t2.maxmark
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
 select * from(
 select 
    *, 
    row_number() over (partition by class order by mark desc) RNum
 From YourTable a
 )x where RNum=1
```